# Spring Integration Inbound-channel-adapter: make one poll and exit

Tags: spring-integration

I need to make a small Spring Integration application that synchronize a table from a JDBC source to another one, and I just need to launch that script just once in a while.

I'd like to make one poll from the inbound channel adapter (wait that the message flow through the chain) and exit the application.

I couldn't find any obvious way to do that: any suggestions?

Comment: thanks Steve for pointing out the right solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Steve suggests correct solution.

You should make your `<poller>` with some long `fixed-delay` do not start a new polling task. Or just stop an `<inbound-channel-adapter>` just after the polling task is run. For this purpose there is just enough make the `channel` as `<publish-subscribe-channel>` and add one more subscriber like:

```
<outbound-channel-adapter channel="processChannel" expression="@adapter.stop()">
```

So, this is the first part: How to make only the single `poll`?

Re. `System.exit()`.

You should add in the end of your flow similar `outbound-channel-adapter`:

```
<outbound-channel-adapter channel="endProcessChannel" expression="T(System).exit()">
```

Comment: thanks Artem! brilliant solution! using the expression to exit the application worked like a charm!

Comment: Apologies for reviving this old issue, but I am dealing with a similar problem and was wondering if you could post a snippet of your solution. My SI app uses an `int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter` and a `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter`. I changed my `<int:channel>` configuration to `<int-publish-subscribe-channel>`, but where do I plug in the `outbound-channel-adapter`s in my solution? Do I need to add the subscriber in Java code? Are there any examples? Sorry, new to Spring (Integration) and still trying to figure out how everything works...

Comment: It doesn't matter where you place that `<oubound-channel-adapter>`. The only important thing that you should use the same `<int-publish-subscribe-channel>` for that adapter. And don't forget to make it as a second subscriber using `order` option. See the XSD documentation for those components and options.

Comment: So I only need one `<int:publish-subscribe-channel>` that both the input and output channel adapters reference?

Comment: Yes, looks like. Input adapters send message to the channel, output - receive.

Comment: Is there a way to specify an order for two different types of outbound channel adapters? I.e. I have publish-subscribe-channel `<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="outputChannel"/>` and then something like `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="fileWriter" channel="outputChannel" directory="${output.directory}" order="1"/>` and `<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="outputChannel" expression="T(System).exit(0)" order="2" />`. Tried this but exit happens before file is written...

Comment: Does not make sense... Exactly the `order` is responsible for that. And you use it correctly. Maybe you have there some *async* hand off? Would be better if you start a new SO thread and share there DEBUG logs to confirm that even with such a config the `exit(0)` happens before file write.

Comment: Seems to be working now with that exact configuration. Not exactly sure why, I might have overlooked something before. If any issues come back I'll open a new thread. Thank you @Artem, you're a great resource!