# Appropriate use of Spring Integration Java DSL plus AmazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-integration, dsl

I'm using a `AmazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource` to read in what may amount to millions of files strewn across an S3 bucket's sub-directories organized by `type >> year >> month >> day >> hour >> {filename}-{uniqueid}.gz`.  Ideally, I'd like to poll and write and have the Synchronizer remember the last place I read from on subsequent polls to retrieve the subsequent batch.  This is NOT the way the above `MessageSource` is designed however.

Anyhow, I can get around that problem by picking a range and reading in contents.

Beside that if I take a simple approach and read in files from one directory on first poll; I want to shutdown (`System.exit`) after that (actually after some processing in comments below).

So, similar to what was asked here:

[Spring Integration Inbound-channel-adapter: make one poll and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048770/spring-integration-inbound-channel-adapter-make-one-poll-and-exit/28049126#28049126)

I want to poll only once and exit after the first poll. (Maybe there's a different way to go about it? I'm open to suggestions).

*app bootstrap*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class DataMigrationApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DataMigrationApp.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DataMigrationApp.class, args);
}

}
```

**UPDATED (2015-09-06)**

*code sample*

```
@Configuration
public class DataMigrationModule {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey}")
private String accessKey;

@Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey}")
private String secretKey;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.bucket}")
private String bucket;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.max-objects-per-batch:1024}")
private int maxObjectsPerBatch;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.accept-subfolders:false}")
private String acceptSubFolders;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.remote-directory}")
private String remoteDirectory;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.local-directory:target/s3-dump}")
private String localDirectory;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.filename-wildcard:}")
private String fileNameWildcard;

@Value("${app.persistent-type:}")
private String persistentType;

@Value("${app.repository-type:}")
private String repositoryType;

@Value("${app.persistence-batch-size:2500}")
private int persistenceBatchSize;

@Autowired
private ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

private final AtomicBoolean invoked = new AtomicBoolean();

public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
    return this.invoked.getAndSet(true) ? null : new Date();
}

private FileToInputStreamTransformer unzipTransformer() {
    FileToInputStreamTransformer transformer = new FileToInputStreamTransformer();
    transformer.setDeleteFiles(true);
    return transformer;
}

private Class<?> repositoryType() {
    try {
        return Class.forName(repositoryType);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        log.error("DataMigrationModule.failure -- (Unknown repository implementation!)", cnfe);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}

private Class<?> persistentType() {
    try {
        return Class.forName(persistentType);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        log.error("DataMigrationModule.failure -- (Unsupported type!)", cnfe);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource<?> amazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
    AmazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource messageSource = new AmazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource();
    messageSource.setCredentials(credentials);
    messageSource.setBucket(bucket);
    messageSource.setMaxObjectsPerBatch(maxObjectsPerBatch);
    messageSource.setAcceptSubFolders(Boolean.valueOf(acceptSubFolders));
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
    if (!fileNameWildcard.isEmpty()) {
        messageSource.setFileNameWildcard(fileNameWildcard);
    }
    String directory = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    if (!localDirectory.startsWith("/")) {
        localDirectory = "/" + localDirectory;
    }
    if (!localDirectory.endsWith("/")) {
        localDirectory = localDirectory + "/";
    }
    directory = directory + localDirectory;
    FileUtils.mkdir(directory);
    messageSource.setDirectory(new LiteralExpression(directory));
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
DirectChannel inputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean 
JdbcRepositoryHandler jdbcRepositoryHandler() {
    return new JdbcRepositoryHandler(repositoryType(), beanFactory);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    // formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                    this.amazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource(),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(this::nextExecutionTime))
            )
            .transform(unzipTransformer())
            // TODO add advised PollableChannel to deal with possible decompression issues

            .split(f -> new FileSplitter())
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(persistentType()))
            // TODO add advised PollableChannel to deal with possible transform issues

            // @see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to
            .aggregate(a -> 
                            a.releaseStrategy(g -> g.size() == persistenceBatchSize)
                            .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                            .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                            .groupTimeoutExpression("size() ge 2 ? 10000 : -1")
                            , null
            )
            .handle(jdbcRepositoryHandler())
            // TODO add advised PollableChannel to deal with possible persistence issue and retry with partial batch
            .get();
    // formatter:on
}

public class JdbcRepositoryHandler extends AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Insertable repository;

    public JdbcRepositoryHandler(Class<?> repositoryClass, ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        repository = (Insertable<?>) beanFactory.getBean(repositoryClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> message) {
        List<?> result = null;
        try {
            result = repository.insert((List<?>) message.getPayload());
        } catch (TransactionSystemException | DataAccessException e) {
            // TODO Quite a bit more work to add retry capability for records that didn't cause failure
            log.error("DataMigrationModule.failure -- (Could not persist batch!)", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
        return result;
    }

}

public class FileToInputStreamTransformer extends AbstractFilePayloadTransformer<InputStream> {

    @Override
    protected InputStream transformFile(File payload) throws Exception {
        return new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(payload));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually not sure what is your question.

You go right way, by the way.

For the `OnlyOnceTrigger` you can use something like this from my test-cases:

```
    private final AtomicBoolean invoked = new AtomicBoolean();

    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        return this.invoked.getAndSet(true) ? null : new Date();
    }

...

    e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(this::nextExecutionTime))
```

For unzipping your file you should do something like this:

```
.<File, InputStream>transform(p -> new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(p)))
```

And you must do this just because there is a `FileSplitter` out-of-the-box component to read files line by line and emit message for each of them. And that one supports `InputStream` as a payload to allow you to avoid loading the entire file to the memory.

So, the next EIP-method in your `IntegrationFlow` is like:

```
.split(new FileSplitter())
```

Not sure after that if you need to aggregate each domain object to some list to make the further batch insertion, because you can do that one by one distributing them via `ExecutorChannel`

As you see there is no reason in the `delete unpacked file` step.

As well as in the last `delete all *.gz files` step. Just because you may rely on the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` to avoid re-reading the same file on the next poll task.

Let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: Thanks Artem! Yes, thanks for understanding what I'm trying to do.  Trying to grok what I'm reading about `Splitters` and `Aggregators`.  The contents of the file are individual JSON payloads. Therefore I assume I could transform again into an instance of a class, take that instance and add to a list.  I expect to call a repo method to insert a batch `List<T>` of records. I believe I'd do this in a `MessageHandler`.  So if lines in file exceeds batch size, I need to stop populating list and call insert, then clear list and continue.  Not sure how to do this with available DSL methods.

Comment: Well you can do that directly with the `.aggregate()` EIP-method with the `MessageCountReleaseStrategy` and `.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)` option.

Comment: I'll try that out and when I have my flow working I'll update this post and give you credit. Finally,  does the aforementioned strategy account for scenario where final batch to be written may not exceed threshold and thus (perhaps never) gets written?

Comment: For the last your concern there is `groupTimeoutExpression` to specify how often the aggregator should try to release non-full groups.

Comment: I will need to cleanup the local directory b/c I do not want to fill it up with synchronized files.  Getting closer to working solution.  Will post when complete.

Comment: So the updated flow as configured above never calls `SaveToRepositoryHandler#handleMessageInternal`.  What might I be missing? Nearly there.

Comment: Two things I learned: 1) No need for `.channel(inputChannel())` between `.from(...)` and `.transform(...)` in `flow()`. 2) If the files were synced to local directory in prior run of app, the `trigger` in flow does not allow them to be re-processed = exactly the behavior I expected, but prevented me from seeing the flow trigger successfully.  A few more tweaks, and I'll have what I need.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and I glad to hear your progress! Not sure where is your problem now but it would be better to have an ExecutorChannel after splitter to process file lines in parallel. You can delete the file from local did using ExpressionEvaluationRequestHandlerAdvice . Sorry, I'm typing from iPhone

Comment: No problems now Artem. Thanks much my for all your advice. I will look into integrating the `ExecutorChannel`. I do wonder if there's any convenience for wrap and re throw checked exceptions as runtime. But that's not a big problem to overcome. My basic flow works now.